# Python compile function, NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python leaner, right now I using `compile` function to get a variable from `input`

```
def main():
    c = compile("n = int(input('>>>'))", "", "single")
    exec(c)
    print(n) # NameError: name 'n' is not defined



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    c = compile("n = int(input('>>>'))", "", "single")
    exec(c)
    print(n) # good, no error
```

same code has different effects in `main()` or under `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: mmm why use compile at all?

Comment: `c=compile("foo")`+`exec(c)` are equivalent to `exec("foo")`.